# Align-items: center not working for one div but working for other divs

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my React component

```
<div className='sidebar'>
        <div className="sidebarItem">
            <span className="sidebarTitle">About Me</span>
            <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1129022.jpg" alt="" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam sit 
               accusantium perferendis earum. Numquam libero vero, fuga, omnis.</p>
        </div>

        <div className="sidebarItem">
            <span className="sidebarTitle">Categories</span>
            <ul className="sidebarList">
                <li className="sidebarListItem">Life</li>
                <li className="sidebarListItem">Music</li>
                <li className="sidebarListItem">Movies</li>
                <li className="sidebarListItem">Tech</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="sidebarItem">
            <span className="sidebarTitle">Follow Us</span>
            <div className="sidebarSocial">
                <i className="sidebarIcon fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
                <i className="sidebarIcon fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                <i className="sidebarIcon fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The following is my CSS:

```
    .sidebar{
    flex: 3;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: hwb(0 96% 1%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.sidebarTitle{
    
    align-self: center;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    border-top: 1px solid #a7a4a4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a4a4;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

.sidebar img{
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

but the align items:center in the sidebar class does not work for the first sidebar item. The following is the result:

[image: Astronaut image]

I want all the divs to be centered but the first one is not being centered. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: It's already centered. Its not visible because of the width of your lorem ipsum text. Give `width: 300px;` to the p element containing lorem ipsum text.

Comment: @subodhkalika I changed the width of lorem ipsum to 300px and now I can see its centered. But I am not able to understand what is happening. Could you please explain in a little more detail ?

also one issue still remains: the text "About me" is still not centered alligned

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
.sidebar {
      flex: 3;
      margin: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      background-color: hwb(0 96% 1%);
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .sidebarItem {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .sidebarTitle {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 80%;
      border-top: 1px solid #a7a4a4;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a4a4;
      font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #222;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .sidebar img {
      margin-top: 15px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    </code>
```

Comment: The following css should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar class centered all children and you should center child contents so :

```
.sidebar {
  flex: 3;
  margin: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: hwb(0 96% 1%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebarTitle {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  border-top: 1px solid #a7a4a4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a4a4;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar img {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
```